# cannot find boost::throw_exception - no package with Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, linker-errors

while building an application using Ubuntu 14.04 I get an linker error telling me that

```
boost::throw_exception
```

can't be found. Amazingly the package libboost-exception-dev does not contain anything linkable that could be used to resolve this problem: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libboost-exception-dev/filelist

So...what package do I have to use/what to link against to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: how about [`libboost-all-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libboost-all-dev)?

Comment: rubenvb: AFAIK this is only a meta-package which only installs the (empty) libboost-exception-dev

Comment: see duplicate: either define `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTION` or define the missing function yourself.